# What does it mean to say "as the clarks swivel around to me"?

Tags: british-english

When [Bercow says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buuD1mh2J4g&t=55s) in formal antiquated Brtishlish,

> I say on advice as the clarks swivel around to me

What does that mean? I have never seen a swiveling "clark"?

Comment: Also see *[How did the pronunciation of the word “derby” evolve?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67720)*

Comment: If you're telling me he can't pronounce "clerks" I'll accept it as an answer, if you can also explain how clerks can swivel. Maybe he means something else there too. I'm not sold on this theory just yet though.

Comment: Do office workers where you are not sit in [swivel chairs](http://nymag.com/strategist/article/best-office-chairs-home-office-chairs.html)?

Comment: Evan, have you got something against British people?

Comment: @choster There is no need to posit "swivel chairs": it is easy to turn smoothly on smooth leather seats such as Parliament enjoys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John Bercow is the Speaker of the House of Commons. His role includes maintaining order during debate, and he may punish members who break the rules of the House. These rules forbid the use of "unparliamentary" language - members may not insult each other or use belittling, sexist or disrespectful language. He is assisted by a number of officials, who are employees of Parliament, that is, they are not elected members, and do not take part in debates or vote to create legislation. Chief among these officials is the Clerk of the House, who advises the Speaker and the House on legal and constitutional matters, and all of the House's procedure and business. He is in turn assisted by the Clerks at the Table whose job is to record the business of the House. They are called this because they sit at the Table of the House, which is in the middle of the house, between the seats of the government and opposition which face each other. The Speaker sits in the Speaker's Chair, which is at one end of the chamber. In order to look at the Speaker, they would have to at least turn their heads, or even as Bercow dramatically said, 'swivel' in their chairs. He said  "I say, on advice" meaning he was speaking having obtained legal advice, for the benefit of the clerks, who would have turned to look at him as they wrote what he was saying, maybe all the more intently because the Speaker's words are always important, and he was rebuking the (then) Foreign Secretary for “inappropriate and frankly sexist” language about a member's wife.

These people, who are called 'clerks', which in British English, rhymes with 'park', 'dark', etc, are in fact highly qualified and senior Parliamentary officers. John Bercow stopped them wearing wigs in 2017, as he said, make the chamber seem “marginally less stuffy”. As you can see, unlike (say) the Canadian table clerks, they do not sit on chairs that came from an office-supply company. The Speaker is behind them, so they would have to swivel considerably to look at him.

[image]

Comment: +1 It may indeed be that the shocked Table Clerks swivel in order to *tender* their advice to the Speaker, who points out to the House that the rebuke he is about to administer is supported by the Clerks.